# Array List .remove function does not remove element entirely, leaving empty spaces in JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I am displaying array list in JTable. 
I have a very simple removing method:

```
@Override
public void DeleteContact(int id) {
    Database c = GetSingleContact(id);
    contactsList.remove(c);
```

Then it is saved to a file.

Everything works correctly but when I remove one element, it leaves empty space filled with 0 in JTable, I cannot get rid of it, size calculation methods still count it as element, and other elements are not renumbered (technically arraylist.remove(x) should do it automatically).

Comment: "I am not sure how to handle it, these errors are very unusual" is irrelevant for the problem. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56449932/edit) the post to be more clear

Comment: Note that method names conventionally begin with a lowercase letter in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> (technically arraylist.remove(x) should do it automatically).

No it should not.

JTable uses a TableModel to hold the data. Any changes to the data need to by done on the TableModel. The TableModel will then notify the table to repaint itself.

If the ArrayList is used as the data store for the TableModel then in the `deleteContact()` method you need to invoke the:

```
 fireTableRowsDeleted( ...);
```

method of your custom TableModel.

See: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example of how to create a custom TableModel for a custom object.

Comment: Ok i know what is my problem. My method fills JTable with simple for loop, and if something is removed, it still detects it and just fills with 0. I need to somehow bypass it in loop or just renumber it in removing method. But thanks for help, it might be useful.

Comment: Ok i have fixed it. But now when i remove, let's say element 5, last element is no longer displayed. Pretty much JTable automatically removes one row, thinking it's no longer needed, but unfortunately it leads to two less rows when i remove one. How to force it to stop? I bet i have to edit TableModel.

Comment: `I bet i have to edit TableModel` - That is exactly what I stated in my answer and I showed you how to create a custom TableModel that does exactly that.